# How can I create a property extension to the Swift String class so that I can compute the opposite of the isEmpty property?

Tags: swift, string

I want to create an extension to the Swift String class which reports back the opposite of the 'isEmpty' property thus;

```
extension String {
   var isNotEmpty: Bool {
      return !iEmpty
   }
}
```

and I would like it to work with the following code;

```
struct LogInViewModel {
   var email: String?
   var password: String?

   var formIsValid: Bool {
      return email?.isNotEmpty && password?.isNotEmpty
   }
}
```

But when I type this code into Xcode, it reports the following error messages;

[image: Xcode error]

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with your `isNotEmpty` method. You would get that same error trying to access any `Bool` property on an optional object in such a conditional statement.

Comment: `return email?.isNotEmpty == true && password?.isNotEmpty == true`

Comment: I have checked Apple documentation for the isEmpty property; and it is similar to my extension so I do not understand why isEmpty works and my extension property does not

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity See [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=optional+type+%22cannot+be+used+as+a+boolean%22).

Comment: @jnpdx that works, thanks! But is it always necessary to add the explicit true boolean values?

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity yes, if you're comparing to an `Optional`, it is necessary. It is _not_ if it's just `Bool` -> `Bool`

Comment: But the isEmpty property in the Apple documentation is not described as an optional. Is it because of optional chaining?

Comment: Yes, when you do the chaining it becomes an optional.

Comment: I see but don't I have to unwrap it in the boolean expression to check it against a literal boolean value true or false?

Comment: @IsaacNewtonGravity no, because there is an overload of `==` that takes two optional, and does the comparison automatically (true iff both side ps are nil, or non nil and equal according to ==). The Boolean literal is implicitly promoted to an optional to make that work (one of Swift’s few implicit conversions)

Comment: You could have also unwrapped the optional manually if an `if let` and such, or you could replace nil with a default to the same effect, like `email?.isNotEmpty ?? false && …`

Comment: `class` does not mean "type". Please edit; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you consider `nil` to be empty then you could add a computed property as an extension to `Optional` when the type is `StringProtocol`

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: StringProtocol {
    public var isNotEmpty: Bool {
        switch self {
        case .none:
            return false
        case .some(let element):
            return element.isEmpty == false
        }
    }
}
```

and for completeness add the same property directly to the protocol

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isNotEmpty: Bool {
        isEmpty == false
    }
}
```

The `StringProtocol` includes both `String` and `SubString` but hopefully that shouldn't be a problem.

Examples

```
var string: String = ""
var optional: String?

if string.isNotEmpty && optional.isNotEmpty {
    //...
}

// or

struct LogInViewModel {
   var email: String
   var password: String?

   var formIsValid: Bool {
       return email.isNotEmpty && password.isNotEmpty
   }
}
```